# Find the isomorphism between $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})= PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Given $\Omega_n(F)=\{x\in F|x^n=1\}$ the group of unit root on field F and define the following groups
$PGL_n(F)=GL_n(F)/F^{\times},PSL_n(F)=SL_n(F)/\Omega_n(F)$
I know that for $n=2$ and $F=\mathbb{C}$ the following is true $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})\cong PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

How can I need to define this isomorphism explictly ? and if the following is true  $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})= PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: It would help if you used more accurate definitions. ${\rm PGL}_n(F) = {\rm GL}_n(F)/Z$, where $Z$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero scalar matrices, and ${\rm PSL}_n(F) = {\rm SL}_n(F)/(Z \cap {\rm SL}_n(F))  \cong {\rm SL}_n(F)Z/Z$. So you need to prove that ${\rm GL}_n(F) = {\rm SL}_n(F)Z$

Comment: this is the information that I was given.

Comment: Well it doesn't make sense. $F^*$ is not a subset of ${\rm GL}_n(F)$.

Comment: Well, given a field $F$, the group of nonzero elements is commonly denoted by $F^\times$, which I guess is notationally close to $F^\star$. Wouldn't be too harsh there, but yes, in doubt, clarify what your notation means.

Comment: Ok, If we assume like you guys suggest how do i solve this?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear the problem is assuming the usual diagonal embedding of $F^\times$ in $GL_n(F)$, but the reader needs to understand this to proceed. (And the problem's definition of $PSL_n(F)$ is equivalent but not identical to the usual definition, as pointed out.) Also Lukas, I don't think $F^\ast$ vs $F^\times$ is what Derek was getting at.

Comment: @ronkurman If $F$ is an algebraically closed field, for any matrix $M \in \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ you have $\det M \neq 0_F$ and you can consider a certain $n$-th root $\lambda$ of $\frac{1}{\det M}$. You will then have $\lambda M \in \mathrm{SL}_n(F)$ and $M=\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathrm{I}_n\right)(\lambda M) \in \left(F^{\times}\mathrm{I}_n\right)\mathrm{SL}_n(F)$. All this for $n \geqslant 1$, the analogous statement for $n=0$ being trivially true ($\mathrm{GL}_0(F)$ is a trivial group).